# Parameter on $\mathrm{SU}(4)$ and $\mathrm{SU}(2)$

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups

From my reading, $\mathrm{SU}(4)$ has 15 parameters and $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ has 3 paramaters that range differently with certain parameter (rotation angle). And all the parameter is linearly independent to each other.

My question are:

1. What the characteristic of each of the parameter?
2. If I choose two of them, what is the reason behind  the theory?
3. Can anyone explain to me or suggest any book/paper to me to understand the parameter itself.

Comment: What is $SU(\cdot)$ ?

Comment: @Qwerty, the special unitary group. SU(2) is the group which preserves $|z_1|^2+|z_2|^2$ for complex numbers $z_1$ and $z_2$.

Comment: can anyone help me to explain the parameter represent what actually? i know it is a angle but in theory it mean what?